# Qual codificação de caracteres (Collation) devo usar em Mysql?

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

Qual é a codificação de caracteres (Collation) mais apropriada para um banco de dados em Mysql que irá armazenar dados da língua portuguesa?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Ambos servem: `latin1_swedish_ci` ou `utf8_general_ci`.

**Para alterar o `CHARSET` e `COLLATION` de um banco existente:**

```
ALTER DATABASE `sua_base` CHARSET = Latin1 COLLATE = latin1_swedish_ci;
```

ou

```
ALTER DATABASE `sua_base` CHARSET = UTF8 COLLATE = utf8_general_ci;
```

**Explicação**

`CHARSET` e `COLLATE` são coisas distintas, no MySQL, cada CHARSET possui COLLATEs, cada um com sua particularidade.

- `latin1_general_ci`: Não há distinção entre letras maiúsculas e minúsculas. Buscando por “teste”, registros como “Teste” ou “TESTE” serão retornados.
- `latin1_general_cs`: Distingue letras maiúsculas e minúsculas. Buscando por “teste” somente retornará “teste”. Opções como “Teste” e “TESTE” não serão retornadas.
- `latin1_swedish_ci`: Não distingue letras minúsculas e maiúsculas e nem caracteres acentuados e com cedilha, ou seja, o registro que contém a palavra “Intuição” será retornado quando houver uma procura pela palavra “intúicao”

[**Fonte**](http://wiki.locaweb.com/pt-br/Resolvendo_problemas_de_caracteres_acentuados_no_MySQL)

Comment: Há alguma razão pra se preferir `Latin1` em vez de `UTF-8`? Eu recomendaria fortemente usar o padrão Unicode, mesmo o AP só prevendo caracteres da língua portuguesa (facilita a interoperabilidade depois), desde é claro que atenda ao que foi pedido (a propósito: existe um `utf8_swedish_ci`).

Comment: Realmente, ambos servem, eu também prefiro `UTF-8`