# Consulta em banco com acentuação na tabela

Tags: php, mysql

Sei que e meio absurdo, mais infelizmente me deparei com uma situação que não sei como contornar

A empresa tem um sistema que grava em baco ACCSSES e algumas tabelas tema acentuação e caracteres especiais Ex: Código - Ação - Preço

E instalei um programa que converte o banco para MYSQL e envia para o meu servidor uma vez por dia, e atualiza o banco

Porem as tabelas tambem sobem com os caracteres especiais.

E preciso realizar as consultas com estes caracteres so que da pau na hora de realizar, existe alguma forma de contornar isso ?

```
SELECT * FROM Campanhas ORDER BY Código ASC
```

Comment: O problema de se criar tabelas com acento, é que você realmente vai ter um monte de problemas em relação a isso. O Windows pode até ter uma certa propensão para fazer essas coisas, mas quando for fazer uma consulta SQL ou mesmo acessar pelo Linux, não vai ter o comportamento esperado. O recomendado sempre é ter o nome das tabelas sem caracteres especiais, facilita sua vida e a vida de quem for dar suporte futuro ao banco

Comment: Tambem sei disso Isaias, mais o problema e que não posso mexer na estrutura do programa do cliente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use o acento invertido:

```
 SELECT * FROM Campanhas ORDER BY `Código` ASC
```

Eu pessoalmente acho uma péssima ideia usar acentos em nomes de colunas, isso sempre terá chances de causar algum problema no momento de enviar as "instruções" para o servidor, seria mais interessante revisar e mudar tudo para sem acento:

```
Código => codigo
Ação => acao
Preço => preco
```

Comment: Tambem acho Guilherme, porem o programa e antigo, a ideia e com isso tentar colocar na cabeça do cliente para futuramente mudar tudo, mais por hora preciso desta solução, e deu certo!

Obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 0):

Coloca isso no seu banco

```
ALTER DATABASE `sua_base` CHARSET = Latin1 COLLATE = latin1_swedish_ci;
```

Mais informações segue o link ->
[Qual codificação de caracteres (Collation) devo usar em Mysql?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/72139/qual-codifica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-caracteres-collation-devo-usar-em-mysql)
Obs. Recomendo que use utf8 no lugar de latin

Comment: Tentei as duas opções a coluna ainda fica com acentuação Código