# Meu SQL não encontra palavras acentuadas

Tags: php, sql

Meu SQL funciona perfeitamente quando a palavra a ser buscada não estiver acentuada, porém, quando a palavra está acentuada, não há resultado na busca.

Meu banco de dados é `mysql` e no `php admin` fiz a consulta, e encontra perfeitamente palavras também acentuadas.

**Segue meu SQL**

```
select id, linkbanner, video, detalhes, mapa, categoria, id_categoria, pagina_descricao, titulo, email, detalhe_contato, endereco, endereco2, site, face, inst, blog, plus, twitter, skype, banner, pop, exibir_pop from anuncios where titulo LIKE '%$strbuscar%'
```

Comment: Qual o encoding do banco? Tem certeza que ele suporta acentos?

Comment: @leofontes utf8_general_ci

Comment: @leofontes Tenho várias tabelas no meu mysql e a exibição das informações ocorrem perfeitamente. Apenas estou com problemas na busca de palavras acentuadas.

Answer (score 0):

Coloca isso no seu banco

```
ALTER DATABASE `sua_base` CHARSET = Latin1 COLLATE = latin1_swedish_ci;
```

Mais informações segue o link -> [Qual codificação de caracteres (Collation) devo usar em Mysql?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/72139/qual-codifica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-caracteres-collation-devo-usar-em-mysql)
Obs. Recomendo que use utf8 no lugar de latin

Comment: Resolveu não. Infelizmente.