# Regex - Como recuperar a primeira ocorrência de duas letras maiúsculas depois de uma vírgula no MySQL?

Tags: mysql, regex

Tenho o seguinte texto:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris sodales porta tempor. Praesent eleifend volutpat nulla, BA at aliquet libero. Vivamus est eros, convallis vitae risus vel, malesuada feugiat felis. Nunc at pharetra nulla. Nam ornare feugiat lectus, sed tincidunt est auctor eget.
```

Eu quero recuperar as duas letras `BA` que podem aparecer em qualquer posição do texto. Serão sempre letras maiúsculas (BA, RJ, DF, SP, ...). O padrão será `A-Z`.

Então isso é que tenho até agora mas não está funcionando:

```
SELECT artigo from artigos WHERE artigo REGEXP ', [A-Z]{2}';
```

- [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html)
- [Regex](https://regex101.com/r/4dCfBe/2)

Comment: Faltou o `WHERE` na query: `SELECT artigo from artigos WHERE artigo REGEXP ', [A-Z]{2}'`. Ou foi erro de digitação ao postar a pergunta?

Comment: Foi erro de digitação. A query retorna o artigo inteiro. Eu queria que retornasse, no exemplo somente 'BA'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A partir do MySQL 8, é possível usar a função [`REGEXP_SUBSTR`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-substr), que retorna somente o trecho correspondente à expressão regular.

Porém, a regex `', [A-Z]{2}'` também retornará a vírgula e o espaço. Para retornar somente as letras, basta usar [`SUBSTR`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substr):

```
SELECT SUBSTR(REGEXP_SUBSTR(artigo, ', [A-Z]{2}', 1, 1, 'c'), 2)
from artigos WHERE artigo REGEXP ', [A-Z]{2}';
```

Com isso, somente as letras `BA` são retornadas pela query.

Os parâmetros `1, 1, 'c'` são respectivamente a posição onde a busca começa (1 é o início da string), qual a ocorrência será retornada (1, pois queremos a primeira ocorrência da regex na string) e `'c'` [faz a busca ser *case sensitive*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-like) *****.

Veja funcionando no [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3bCNtCpwPYBGWTLyvtvraV/0).

---

***** A princípio a regex `[A-Z]` já deveria pegar somente letras maiúsculas, mas testando no DB Fiddle ele estava fazendo a busca *case insensitive* e acabava pegando as letras `co` do trecho `, consectetur`. Passando a opção `'c'` a busca passou a ser *case sensitive* e o `BA` foi encontrado corretamente. Provavelmente isso acontece porque o *default* do MySQL é usar as regras do charset e [*collation*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-collation-coercibility.html) dos parâmetros da busca, e o DB Fiddle deve usar um cujo *default* é *case insensitive*. Para saber mais, veja [aqui](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/15250) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/72139/112052).

Para versões anteriores ao MySQL 8, a função `REGEXP_SUBSTR` não está disponível. Neste caso, *talvez* seja possível simular o resultado (ou chegar próximo dele) com substrings, usando [algo parecido com isso](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2742764). Ou simplesmente pegue a string inteira e extraia o trecho desejado usando uma linguagem de programação - pois estas geralmente possuem um suporte a regex melhor que o do MySQL.